# Maximize profit with disregard to number of pickup-delivery done OR tools

Tags: or-tools

I am trying to maximize profit, whether I deliver all pickups-deliveries does not matter.

I tried setting `SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles` to use negative profit instead of cost callback; however, this does not work, an I get `no solution` often, my thought is that cost cannot be negative. Is this correct?

Adding `AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer` with profit callback does not seem to work, because it runs after the solutions are already found, and therefore it will not eliminate deliveries that are not profitable. Is this correct?

My gut feeling is that I need set a metric (profit dimension?) that evaluates the performance of solver, and use `AddDisjunction` with punishment for missing pickup-delivery set to 0, to eliminate not profitable deliveries. Is something like this possible? If not, what is the recommended approach?

**Edit:**

Here is my code, it is a very small modification of: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery

```
"""Simple Pickup Delivery Problem (PDP)."""

from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [
            0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
            468, 776, 662
        ],
        [
            548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
            1016, 868, 1210
        ],
        [
            776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
            1130, 788, 1552, 754
        ],
        [
            696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
            1164, 560, 1358
        ],
        [
            582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
            1050, 674, 1244
        ],
        [
            274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
            514, 1050, 708
        ],
        [
            502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
            514, 1278, 480
        ],
        [
            194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
            662, 742, 856
        ],
        [
            308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
            320, 1084, 514
        ],
        [
            194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
            274, 810, 468
        ],
        [
            536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
            730, 388, 1152, 354
        ],
        [
            502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
            308, 650, 274, 844
        ],
        [
            388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
            536, 388, 730
        ],
        [
            354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
            342, 422, 536
        ],
        [
            468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
            342, 0, 764, 194
        ],
        [
            776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
            388, 422, 764, 0, 798
        ],
        [
            662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
            536, 194, 798, 0
        ],
    ]
    data['pickups_deliveries'] = [
        [1, 6],
        [2, 10],
        [4, 3],
        [5, 9],
        [7, 8],
        [15, 11],
        [13, 12],
        [16, 14],
    ]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 4
    data['depot'] = 0

    data['revenue'] = {6: 1000000,
                       10: 100,
                       3: 100,
                       9: 100,
                       8: 100,
                       11: 100,
                       12: 100,
                       14: 100
                       }

    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    total_distance = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
    print('Total Distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))


def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Define cost of each arc.

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Define Transportation Requests.
    for request in data['pickups_deliveries']:
        pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
        delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
        routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
        routing.solver().Add(
            routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
                delivery_index))
        routing.solver().Add(
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))

    for node, revenue in data["revenue"].items():
        routing.AddDisjunction(
            [manager.NodeToIndex(node)], revenue
        )

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I addeded:

```
data['revenue'] = {6: 1000000,
                   10: 100,
                   3: 100,
                   9: 100,
                   8: 100,
                   11: 100,
                   12: 100,
                   14: 100
                   }
```

and

```
for node, revenue in data["revenue"].items():
    routing.AddDisjunction(
        [manager.NodeToIndex(node)], revenue)
```

When I run this code all pickup-deliveries get delivered (even if I hard code `revenue` to 0). I am looking for a solution where only `[1, 6]` is delivered, because it is the only one that gives profit.

I think I see where my issue is coming from. When pickup deliveries constraints are setup, the cost is minimized given these constraints. And since all of these constraints can be satisfied all pickup-deliveries get delivered.

Is there a way to make pickup-deliveries constraints soft, and focus on minimizing the cost (plus the punishment)?

Comment: to make a PDP soft, you need to add 2 disjunctions, one for the pickup, and one for the delivery.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, This indeed works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a penalty of 0 to deliveries, the solver will happily drop all of them.
Also, non profitable is in the context of the route. Therefore, you need to tweak the penalties to get what you want.

Response to edit:

To make a PDP soft, you need to add 2 disjunctions, one for the pickup, and one for the delivery.

Comment: Thank You for your reply, I have updated my question with a concrete example, can you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I ended up using:

```py
    """Simple Pickup Delivery Problem (PDP)."""

    from __future__ import print_function
    from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
    from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
    
    
    def create_data_model():
        """Stores the data for the problem."""
        data = {}
        data['distance_matrix'] = [
            [
                0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
                468, 776, 662
            ],
            [
                548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
                1016, 868, 1210
            ],
            [
                776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
                1130, 788, 1552, 754
            ],
            [
                696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
                1164, 560, 1358
            ],
            [
                582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
                1050, 674, 1244
            ],
            [
                274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
                514, 1050, 708
            ],
            [
                502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
                514, 1278, 480
            ],
            [
                194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
                662, 742, 856
            ],
            [
                308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
                320, 1084, 514
            ],
            [
                194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
                274, 810, 468
            ],
            [
                536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
                730, 388, 1152, 354
            ],
            [
                502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
                308, 650, 274, 844
            ],
            [
                388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
                536, 388, 730
            ],
            [
                354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
                342, 422, 536
            ],
            [
                468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
                342, 0, 764, 194
            ],
            [
                776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
                388, 422, 764, 0, 798
            ],
            [
                662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
                536, 194, 798, 0
            ],
        ]
        data['pickups_deliveries'] = [
            [1, 6],
            [2, 10],
            [4, 3],
            [5, 9],
            [7, 8],
            [15, 11],
            [13, 12],
            [16, 14],
        ]
        data['num_vehicles'] = 4
        data['depot'] = 0
    
        data['revenue'] = {(1, 6): 1000000,
                           (2, 10): 100,
                           (4, 3): 100,
                           (5, 9): 10000,
                           (7, 8): 100,
                           (15, 11): 100,
                           (13, 12): 100,
                           (16, 14): 100
                           }
    
        return data
    
    
    def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
        """Prints solution on console."""
        total_distance = 0
        for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
            index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
            plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
            route_distance = 0
            while not routing.IsEnd(index):
                plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
                previous_index = index
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
                route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                    previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
            plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
            print(plan_output)
            total_distance += route_distance
        print('Total Distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))
    
    
    def main():
        """Entry point of the program."""
        # Instantiate the data problem.
        data = create_data_model()
    
        # Create the routing index manager.
        manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                               data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    
        # Create Routing Model.
        routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    
        # Define cost of each arc.
    
        def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
    
        transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    
        # Add Distance constraint.
        dimension_name = 'Distance'
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index,
            0,  # no slack
            3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
            True,  # start cumul to zero
            dimension_name)
        distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
        distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
    
        # Define Transportation Requests.
        for request in data['pickups_deliveries']:
            pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
            delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
            routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
            routing.solver().Add(
                routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
                    delivery_index))
            routing.solver().Add(
                distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
                distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))
    
        for node, revenue in data["revenue"].items():
            start, end = node
            routing.AddDisjunction(
                [manager.NodeToIndex(end)], revenue
            )
    
            routing.AddDisjunction(
                [manager.NodeToIndex(start)], 0
            )
    
        # Setting first solution heuristic.
        search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
        search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
            routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION)
    
        # Solve the problem.
        solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    
        # Print solution on console.
        if solution:
            print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```