# OR-Tools: TSP with Profits

Tags: or-tools

is there an option to calculate the TSP with Profits using OR-Tools?
I tried to implement a revenue for every end node

```
 data['revenue'] = {(1, 0): 0,
                   (1, 2): 100,
                   (1, 3): 10,
                   (1, 4): 10000000000,    
                   (2, 0): 0,
                   (2, 1): 1000,
                   (2, 3): 10,
                   (2, 4): 10000000000,
                   (3, 0): 0,
                   (3, 1): 1000,
                   (3, 2): 100,
                   (3, 4): 10000000000,
                   (4, 0): 0,
                   (4, 1): 1000,
                   (4, 2): 100,
                   (4, 3): 10
                   }
```

and then i added from this question: [Maximize profit with disregard to number of pickup-delivery done OR tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768329/maximize-profit-with-disregard-to-number-of-pickup-delivery-done-or-tools)

```
 for node, revenue in data["revenue"].items():
    start, end = node
    routing.AddDisjunction(
        [manager.NodeToIndex(end)], revenue
    )

    routing.AddDisjunction(
        [manager.NodeToIndex(start)], 0
    )
```

this is not working unfortunately. I always get solutions, that are not making sense.
Can someone help or give me an advice, how to implement profits into the TSP with OR-Tools?

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding start or end node in a Disjunction makes no sense...
2. AddDisjunction must be applied to each node (or pair) BUT start and end nodes.

```py
for node, revenue in data["revenue"].items():
    pickup, delivery = node
    pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(pickup)
    delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(delivery)
    routing.AddDisjunction(
      [pickup_index, delivery_index], revenue, 2 # cardinality
    )
```

3. Does your key value in your dict are pair of nodes ? seems to be coordinate to me...